# How do I clone a stack of Integers?

Tags: java, integer, stack, clone

This seemingly extremely easy problem has baffled me for hours.  I'm trying to clone a stack of integer objects.  I've tried

```
Stack<Integer> newStack = (Stack<Integer>)oldStack.clone();
```

However that gives me an error saying `clone() has protected access in java.lang.Object`

My best guess is that because Integer doesn't implement `clone()`, so I'm getting that error.  So how should I clone a stack of integers then?

Comment: You're not using `java.util.Stack`

Comment: How are we supposed to know? You havent provided an SSCCE.

Comment: I've imported nothing but `java.util.*`.  Does my OS (Mac OS X 10.8) have anything to do with this problem?

Comment: provide an sccee. During its preparation, you will likely discover your problem.

Comment: May be this is why we should not import  using .*  . There can be another Stack which is imported by another import statement.

Comment: Sorry for the bother everyone.  Long story short, don't rely on `java.util.*`.  Import Stack using `java.util.Stack`

Comment: If I were you, I would use [`Deque`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Deque.html) using the [`ArrayDeque`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayDeque.html) implementation instead of `Stack`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Somehow there's another Stack class hidden somewhere.  Don't know why, but import Stack using

```
import java.util.Stack
```

instead of relying on

```
import java.util.*
```

Answer (score 5):

Are you sure you are using java.util.Stack? It inherits clone from Vector

```
  public synchronized Object clone() {...
```

I ran this test

```
Stack<Integer> st = new Stack<Integer>();
st.push(1);
Stack<Integer> clone = (Stack<Integer>)st.clone();
System.out.println(clone);
```

it gives

[1]

Comment: Then I have no idea what I'm using.  The only thing I've imported is `java.util.*`

Comment: Hi, is `Stack<Integer> clone = (Stack<Integer>)st.clone();` any different than `Stack<Integer> clone = new Stack().addAll(st);`

Comment: @Subin The result is the same, but clone is supposed to work anyway. We are trying to find out why it does not work for TheAmateurProgrammer

Comment: ok, best guess is he is not using java.util.Stack as others mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

You dont have to clone Integer s as Integer is immutable.

You can take a copy by `new Stack().addAll(otherstack)`

Comment: So how would I clone a **stack** of Integer's?

Comment: I've tried using `addAll` already.  I get `cannot find symbol  symbol  : method addAll(Stack<java.lang.Integer>)` instead.

Comment: can you share that code. Stack do have addAll Method inherited from Vector

Answer (score 1):

According to the [Java API documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Stack.html), Stack does implement cloneable. Are you sure oldStack is indeed of type Stack?

**Edit**

I've tested this with the following code and didn't get any exception:

```
    Stack<Integer> stack = new Stack<Integer>();
    stack.push(1);
    stack.push(2);
    stack.push(3);
    stack.push(4);

    Stack<Integer> s2 = (Stack<Integer>) stack.clone();

    while (!s2.empty()) {
        System.out.println(s2.pop());
    }
```

Comment: Yes, I'm absolutely sure oldStack is a stack of Integers.

Comment: `Stack` is `Cloneable`, but `Integer` isn't. See my answer.

Comment: clone is not supposed to be deep. I think it does not run clone on the objects in the internal array. Do you have a reference for that?

Comment: "clone is not supposed to be deep" - well, that's really on a case-by-case basis. I take it back: you're right about Stack, its clone() isn't deep.

Answer (score -1):

This works :

```
Stack<Node> st1=(Stack<Node>) st2.clone();
```

Comment: It worked for me. for integer also